# Xcode Google Sign In using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-authentication

I implemented "Google Log In" in my app, and I want to make sure a segue occures only after a SUCCESSFUL log in using Google. I'm not sure how to do that.

This is my code :

```
@IBAction func GoogleSignInButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

    LoadHomeScreen(sender: sender) // Notice this should only occure after 
                                     SUCCESSFUL LOGIN    
}
```

Any idea how I can do this? I need some kind of method that waits for a successful login or a failed on (For any reason), and then call LoadHomeScreen only after a successful login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `self` as a delegate to `GIDSignIn` object. That delegate will get notified when the login was successful using `googleSignIn` callback method, and when `error` parameter in that method is `nil`, you know the sign in was successful. So you just need to implement that method and act upon it:

```
func googleSignIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // successful login
        LoadHomeScreen(sender: sender)
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this out now, it seems I had another bug I fixed.

Comment: Well, I just implemented the code you wrote, and when Log in is successful, it won't get there. I have this function implemented:

public func signIn(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
                       withError error: Error!)

But it won't get there either. I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @MathEnthusiast the only thing in this case that comes to my mind is that there's been some change in the API - use xcode code completion to generate that method's declaration (there might be a difference in just a small detail)..

Comment: @MathEnthusiast how does it look?

Comment: public func signIn(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) is what the tutorial told me to implement

Comment: @MathEnthusiast dont trust tutorial on it, but use Xcode code completion to suggest the correct method

Comment: @MathEnthusiast comment out the old method, and start writing `didSignIn` in the view controller, and the xcode should show you a list of functions that you can implement there.. there should be only one with this exact text, so select it and xcode will generate the method stub.. then just fill in the implementatin

Comment: It's weird, but after commenting that function out, it won't auto-complete anything that looks like it when I type didSignIn/signIn... I'm a bit lost...

Comment: @MathEnthusiast add the link to the tutorial you follow

Answer (score 0):

First make sure delegates are all set to self , also it's better to set them in `viewDidLoad` not in the button action

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()
```

Implement this method

```
 func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {

           guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

            print("GooSDKAccessIdToken \(authentication.idToken)")

            print("GooSDKAccessToken120 \(authentication.accessToken)")

            let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                              accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential)
            {
                (user, error) in
                if error != nil
                {
                    print("Login google+ failed. \(String(describing: error))")

                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("invOk", comment: ""), style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


                } else
                {
                    print("Logged google+ Success!")

                    self.LoadHomeScreen()

                }
            }



}
```